# Gitlab CI - eslint witout output

Tags: console, devops, gitlab-ci, eslint

I use React JS and I want to make a pipeline that uses eslint to check the code.

Part of the gitlab ci code in charge of linting

```
Lint React:
  stage: pre-build tests
  only:
    refs:
      - branches
  except:
    refs:
      - schedules
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/image/custom-image/admin:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  allow_failure: true 
  before_script:
    - mkdir $CI_PROJECT_DIR/node_modules
    - cp -a $NODE_MODULE_FILES/. $CI_PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/
    - npm install -g eslint
    - npm install -g eslint-plugin-react
  script:
    - eslint ./src/**/*.js
```

Problem is that there is no output of that lint, on my local consol i get errors, but on the GitLab job output i don't get anything

Output:

```
$ npm install -g eslint
 /usr/local/bin/eslint -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js
 + eslint@6.8.0
 added 134 packages from 84 contributors in 8.193s
 $ npm install -g eslint-plugin-react
 > core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint-plugin-react/node_modules/core-js-pure
 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
 npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.19.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
 + eslint-plugin-react@7.19.0
 added 42 packages from 21 contributors in 3.681s
 $ eslint ./src/**/*.js
Running after_script
00:02
Saving cache
```

I have a similar problem in other situations, but in this case verbose mode helps.